# Dumping log messages to console when executing a STAX file

Tags: python, xml, automation

I have an XML file (STAX) which i execute from command line

```
[root@local ~]# staf local STAX EXECUTE FILE "/root/test2.xml" 
ARGS "{'command':'ls'}" WAIT RETURNRESULT
```

And get following output ..

```
Response
--------
{
  Job ID         : 57
  Start Date-Time: 20130405-18:27:13
  End Date-Time  : 20130405-18:27:13
  Status         : Normal
  Result         : 0
  Job Log Errors : []
  Testcase Totals: {
    Tests : 0
    Passes: 0
    Fails : 0
  }
}
```

Script contents ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE stax SYSTEM "stax.dtd">
<stax>
<defaultcall function="runCommand"/>

<function name="runCommand">
    <function-list-args>
            <function-required-arg name="command"/>
    </function-list-args>

    <try>
           <sequence>

            <script>print("This");</script>
            <message>'%s  %s:  is a:  %s' % (STAXCurrentTestcase, STAXCurrentFunction, command)</message>
            <log>'test'</log>

            <return>0</return>
        </sequence>

        <catch exception="'eTerminateFunction'" var="eInfo">
            <sequence>
                    <log level="'fail'">'%s  %s:  Terminating function   Error: %s' % (STAXCurrentTestcase, STAXCurrentFunction, eInfo)</log>
                    <tcstatus result="'fail'">eInfo</tcstatus>
                    <return>1</return>
            </sequence>
        </catch>
    </try>
</function>
</stax>
```

How come none of the logging is dumped to console during or after execution? 
for `<log>`, `<message>` or the python `<script>print("This")</script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as i Know

> The STAX EXECUTE WAIT RETURNRESULT request returns in the result exactly what it is supposed to return as documented in section "EXECUTE", sub-section "Results", in the [STAX User's Guide at](http://staf.sourceforge.net/current/STAX/staxug.html#Header_Execute). It returns more summary type information about the job and any errors that were logged in the STAX Job log.
>
> The  element in a STAX job logs a message in the STAX job user log as documented in section "log: Log a Message in the STAX Job User Log" in the [STAX User's Guide at](http://staf.sourceforge.net/current/STAX/staxug.html#Header_Log_Element) . This section says to look at the "STAX Logging" section, sub-section ["Querying the STAX Job User Logs" at](http://staf.sourceforge.net/current/STAX/staxug.html#Header_StaxLogging)  for more information on how to query a STAX Job User log to view the messages that you've logged in a STAX job.
>
> Or, to query the STAX Job User log for a STAX job with job ID 1 on the STAX service machine, you could specify:

```
STAF local LOG QUERY MACHINE {STAF/Config/MachineNickname} LOGNAME STAX_Job_1_User
```

> **Note:** when you run a STAX job, a STAX Job log is created.  This is different from the STAX Job User log.  A STAX Job User log is only created if the STAX job logged data in it (e.g. via a  element).
>
> The  element in a STAX job sends a message to the STAX Monitor as documented in section "message: Send a Message to the STAX Monitor" in the STAX User's Guide at http://staf.sourceforge.net/current/STAX/staxug.html#Header_Message_Element.  To see the messages sent to the STAX Monitor, you need to run the job via the STAX Monitor.  The messages will be displayed in the "Messages" panel when running the STAX job.
>
> As to where the output from a "print" statement within a  element goes, this is controlled by the PYTHONOUTPUT parameter that can be specified when registering the STAX service or changed via the STAX SET PYTHONOUTPUT request, or overridden for a particular STAX job when executing a STAX job (by specifying the PYTHONOUTPUT option on a STAX EXECUTE request or via the STAX Monitor).  This is talked about in section ["Installation and Configuration". sub-section "STAX service machine" at](http://staf.sourceforge.net/current/STAX/staxug.html#Header_StaxServiceMach)   and section "EXECUTE" in the STAX User's Guide.
>
> The default is to log the Python print output in the STAX Job User log.  So, if you're using the default setting, the "print" output will be logged to the STAX Job User log (same place where the message in a  element is logged) and you can view it by querying the STAX Job User log as I talked about above.
>
> - PYTHONOUTPUT specifies where Python stdout/stderr should be redirected (e.g. if you use the print statement in a  element in a STAX job). Valid values are the following (not case-sensitive):
> - "JobUserLog" indicates to log the Python output in the STAX Job User log. This is the default.
> - "Message" indicates to send the Python output to the STAX Monitor and display it in the Messages panel.
> - "JobUserLogAndMsg" indicates to log the Python output in the STAX Job User log and to send it to the STAX Monitor and display it in the Messages panel.
> - "JVMLog" indicates to write the Python output in the JVM Log for the STAX service using the following format so that you will know which STAX job originated the output and at what time:
>     <`Timestamp> [JobID: <JobID>] <Python Output>`